# How can a branch instruction be mispredicted AND retired?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture

Intel has a hardware event counter called:

BR_MISP_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES

where the description says:

> Mispredicted macro branch instructions retired.

But *retired* instructions are those which were correctly-required:

> Modern processors execute much more instructions that the program flow
>   needs. This is called "speculative execution".
>
> Then the instructions that were "proven" as indeed needed by flow are
>   "retired".

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/311170

So how can a branch **misprediction** instruction be proven-as-needed, too?

Comment: The number of instructions *started* is not equal to the number of instructions *retired*.  There are more started instructions, some are not used because the pipeline got flushed due to mispredictions and exceptions.  You only care about retired ones, the kind whose side-effects were actually used. So the counter tells you how many of those were branches that took a long time.

Comment: @HansPassant I know this. The problem is how Intel badly word the description. Are they referring to all instructions in that branch, or the actual branch instruction....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of order machines work by speculating past multiple branches at the same time. When a branch is found to have been wrongly predicted the CPU will clean up any unwanted state and return execution to that instruction so that the correct path can be taken.

So while many speculatively executed instructions (including branches) are discarded, the single instruction that *causes* the mispredicted branch is not. That branch instruction takes effect and is retired, after having being mispredicted.

This counter seems to record such instructions.

Comment: Ok if I understand you correctly- I have a branch, I predict it (wrong, but I dont know that yet) it does ADD, SUB etc- these ADD and SUB instructions (uops really) are retired and thennnnnn I detect the branch misprediction. Are you saying this event counts the number of instructions like ADD and SUB, retired but from mispredicted branches?

Comment: Is BACLEARS.ANY the best for just counting how many branch mispredictions then?

Comment: No, it only counts branch instructions themselves. I think this is the right counter if you want to know the number of mispredictions.

Comment: It's hard to know given documentation of this quality. :)

Comment: @user997112, a BACLEAR is not a branch misprediction, but an earlier block due to inability to provide a prediction in the first place.